# Pass csrf token from Laravel to Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Pass **csrf** token from **Laravel to Vue**
I have a separate Vue app for client and Laravel for back-end (API). I use Cookies so I need csrf protection. How can I pass csrf token from server to client? Pushing token from server to client every XX seconds can be a sollution

Comment: you are serving Vue files from Laravel?

Comment: Since its an api, can't you just turn off the `xsrf` middleware, while keeping the `cookies` middleware on?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token)

If you add this to your blade template in the head then you can always pull the CSRF token from there

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

And you can then fetch said CSRF token by doing this

```
$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
```

Comment: He is using a standalone Vue app, which means that he's not able to use the helper