# How to retrieve laravel CSRF token using separated vue frontend

Tags: laravel, vue.js, csrf

Is there a way to pass Laravel csrf token to Vue given that the Laravel backend and the Vue frontend are separated from each other (in diferent directory and in diferent subdomains) ??

I'm building an application and would like to have separated backend and frontend for organization purposes and for because it facilitates team work. So, it would be something like:

- api.mydomainexample.com (Laravel backend)
- mydomainexample.com (Vue frontend for public)
- admin.mydomainexample.com (Vue Frontend for admin only)

Is this possible? What I thought was maybe running a nodejs server for the frontend project and make the nodejs server communicate with the laravel server. Don't know how to do that.

I found [similiar stackoverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50325287/pass-csrf-token-from-laravel-to-vue), but the responses from them do not solve my problem. The best thing I found was [this](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59389557/how-to-pass-a-csrf-token-safely-to-a-separate-vuejs-frontend), which proposes to use Laravel passport. But, is the proposal the only one that works? If so, does Laravel passport protect users from CSRF attacks?

Actually, if there is an workaround which enables to have separated backend and frontend while protecting against CSRF tokens, then that would be perfect!

Comment: Where are you serving your vue files, from a nodejs server or laravel's rotue?

Comment: Currently, I'm serving the vue files from Laravel web routes. But I plan to create a nodejs server to serve the files because the goal is to separate backend from frontend

Comment: Alternatively you can use Laravel Sanctum to handle your frontend authenticatio ; it does the csrf thing for SPAs pretty well and it is lighter than passport.

Comment: We kinda have similar system at my workplace, we use laravel routes for serving vue files, using nodejs and socketio just for real time communication. I actually can not say anything about completely seperate files..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/sanctum)

## LARAVEL BACKEND

1. Install Sanctum via Composer

   `composer require laravel/sanctum`

---

2. Publish the Sanctum configuration and migration files

   `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Laravel\Sanctum\SanctumServiceProvider"`

---

3. Run your migrations - Sanctum will add a table to store API tokens

   `php artisan migrate`

---

4. Add Sanctum's middleware to your **api** middleware group in your `App/Http/Kernel.php`

---

```
use Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful;

'api' => [
    EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
    'throttle:60,1',
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
],
```

5. Configure which domains your SPA will be making requests from. From the docs:

> *You may configure these domains using the stateful configuration option in your sanctum configuration file. This configuration setting determines which domains will maintain "stateful" authentication using Laravel session cookies when making requests to your API.*

So - Update your `config\sanctum.php` to include something like this:

```
/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Stateful Domains
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Requests from the following domains / hosts will receive stateful API
    | authentication cookies. Typically, these should include your local
    | and production domains which access your API via a frontend SPA.
    |
    */

    'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', 'localhost,localhost:8000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1')),
```

---

6. Configure your `config/cors.php`

---

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
    | or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
    | in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
    |
    | To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
    |
    */

    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie', 'login', '*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,

];
```

7. Configure your `config/session.php`

---

```
/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Domain
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
    | in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
    | available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
    |
    */

    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
```

8. In your `.env`, add the following:

---

```
// Change .your-site.local to whatever domain you are using
// Please note the leading '.'

SESSION_DOMAIN=.your-site.local 
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=your-site.local:8000
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS=http://app.your-site.local:8000
```

---

9. Run a `php artisan config:clear`

---

## VUE FRONTEND

1. In your front-end, create the following folder/file structure
   `@/src/services/api.js`

****api.js**:**

```
import axios from 'axios';

const apiClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL,
    withCredentials: true,
});

export default apiClient;
```

In the root directory, place an **.env** file with the following in it:

```
VUE_APP_API_URL= 'http://api.your-site.local'
```

2. To authenticate, your SPA should first make a request to the `/sanctum/csrf-cookie`. This sets the `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie. This token needs to be sent on subsequent requests ( axios will handle this for you automatically ). Immediately after, you'll want to send a `POST` request to your Laravel `/login` route.

On your Vue front-end login component:

---

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import apiClient from '../services/api';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
        email: null,
        password: null,
        loading: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {

    async login() {
      this.loading = true; // can use this to triggle a :disabled on login button
      this.errors = null;

        try {
          await apiClient.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie'); 
          await apiClient.post('/login', {
            email: this.email,
            password: this.password
          });

          // Do something amazing
          
        } catch (error) {
          this.errors = error.response && error.response.data.errors;
        }

      this.loading = false;
    },

  },
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try it out on the next couple of day and let you know if it worked!

Comment: Perfect! That was perfect! It worked like a charm and was easy to install ! Thank you very much, sincerely

Comment: My pleasure @StudentofScience ! I just went through the same thing, so good timing all around