# How to configure separate Laravel and Vuejs application?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am trying to build and web application Using Laravel in backend and Vuejs in frontend. I want to keep the application setup completely separate. So that Laravel application can run on a port and Vuejs application will run on a different port of the same server. Can you please help to find out how can I set up my web application in this manner? How to configure Laravel as it can communicate with separate Vuejs application? Or share me some resources this describes the solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you actually try to google this? I found this tutorial after a simple google search: https://dev.to/oktadev/build-a-basic-crud-app-with-laravel-and-vue-2oj8 It's a year old tutorial, but should get you started. And another one: https://dzone.com/articles/the-ultimate-vuejs-amp-laravel-crud-tutorial

Comment: If you're planning on going the SPA route, I just [wrote an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63200511/how-to-retrieve-laravel-csrf-token-using-separated-vue-frontend/63201361#63201361) that goes over a basic setup.

Comment: @FullStackOfPancakes that seems like exactly what I am searching for. I will try it and let you know. Thank you!