# Correct configuration Laravel Sanctum and Angular

Tags: angular, laravel, cookies, laravel-sanctum

I'm trying to connect my angular-app to my Laravel 7 using Sanctum.

The backend is running in a wamp virtualhost calls (pruebas.test) and the config is like that:

.env:

```
APP_URL=http://pruebas.test
SESSION_DOMAIN=pruebas.test
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:4300
```

config/cors.php

```
paths' => [
        'api/*',
        '/login',
        '/logout',
        '/sanctum/csrf-cookie'
    ],

'supports_credentials' => true,
```

config/session.php (now is same_site equals none but I tried with lax, strict and null options)

```
'same_site' => "none",
```

kernel.php

```
'api' => [
            EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:60,1',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],`
```

At the front we work with Angular 10 and we implement a method to login with this code:

```
login(): void {
    const url = `http://pruebas.test/sanctum/csrf-cookie`;
    this.http.get<any>(url).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);

      // the response is correct but not set the cookies
      // this.http.post<any>('http://pruebas.test/api/v1/login', { password: 'password', 'email': 'twatsica@example.com' }).subscribe(success => {
      //   console.log(success);
      //   this.http.get<any>('http://pruebas.test/api/v1/articles').subscribe(success => console.log(success));
      // }
      //   , error => console.log(error))
    })
  }
```

Also we have and interception to add withCredentials at the header request:

```
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    headerName = 'X-XSRF-TOKEN';

    constructor(private tokenService: HttpXsrfTokenExtractor) { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        req = req.clone({
            withCredentials: true
        })
        console.log(req);
        req.headers.set('withCredentials', 'true');
        if (req.method === 'GET' || req.method === 'HEAD') {
            return next.handle(req);
        }

        const token = this.tokenService.getToken();

        // Be careful not to overwrite an existing header of the same name.
        if (token !== null && !req.headers.has(this.headerName)) {
            req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set(this.headerName, token) });
        }

        return next.handle(req);
    }
}
```

But the browers never set the cookies, dependes the `'same_site'` configuration we have differents reponses but the cookie never set.

same_site=lax => This Set-Cookie was blocked because it had the "SameSite=lax" attribute but came form a cross-site resposne which was not the response to a top-level navigation.

same_site=strict => This Set-Cookie was blocked because it had the "SameSite=strict" attribute but came form a cross-site resposne which was not the response to a top-level navigation.

same_site=none => This Set-Cookie was blocked because it had the "SameSite=none" attribute but did not have the "Secure" attribute, which is required in order to use "SameSite=none"

Some ideas?

Comment: I just went through this myself with Laravel & Sanctum + Vue.js. Can check my answer out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63200511/how-to-retrieve-laravel-csrf-token-using-separated-vue-frontend/63201361#63201361) - maybe it helps get you in the right direction?

Comment: Thank @FullStackOfPancakes. I assume that ```SESSION_DOMAIN``` is my api domain and in ```SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS``` third party clients (Angular, VUE projects) domains

Comment: If you had `api.yoursite.local` and `app.yoursite.local`, then `SESSION_DOMAIN=.yoursite.local` and `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=yoursite.local:8000`. Take special note of the leading `.` on the **SESSION_DOMAIN**

Comment: Are you seeing anything in your server logs? Likewise, what do you see in Chrome Developer Tools, e.g. what's the exact value of the `set-cookie` header that is being sent? Detailed debugging guide at: https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/test-debug

Comment: @FullStackOfPancakes my api and my client are in differents domains ```client => localhost:4300``` and ```api => api.pruebas.test```