# Request error 419 unknown status to laravel from nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, nuxtjs

after many searches we found this codes but is not for nuxt:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
```

.env file in laravel:

```
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_DOMAIN=null
SANCTUM_STATEFULL_DOMAINS='localhost:3000'
```

also in app/http\providers\Jetstream file:

```
Jetstream::defaultApiTokenPermissions(['create','read']);
```

[image: login page screenshot]

is possible and good idea add something in our nuxt.config.js axios object? if so what's key and value?

nuxt.config.js file:

```
 axios: {
        baseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
        credentials: true,
      },
```

ALSO when we add '*' to our verifyCsrf middleware we see:

[image]

Comment: https://markohoven.com/2018/01/23/419-http-status-code/

Comment: what we should do in verifycsrf middleware? we added 'localhost:3000/*' but still not works. and for solution 2 can we move jetstream default routes from web to api routes? how can we do that?

Comment: Are you trying to make an SPA? Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63200511/how-to-retrieve-laravel-csrf-token-using-separated-vue-frontend/63201361#63201361)  help point you in the right direction? Doesn't use Jetstream, but uses a Vue/Nuxt front end to speak to a Laravel back-end API

Comment: SPA yes. what should we enter as SESSION_DOMAIN value in our case? every thing we entered says rejected by invalid domain! just null value says no error!